# How can I get an ordered list of columns values in a row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, columnsorting

I have a table that listed six unique numbers in a row, on their specified columns:

| id | n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 | n5 | n6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 44 | 11 | 32 | 14 | 28 | 19 |

How I can use MySQL to get the row values in an ascending order?

| id | n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 | n5 | n6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 14 | 19 | 28 | 32 | 44 |

Thank you!

I tried ORDER BY FIELD(), subqueries and concatenation, but nothing works.

```
SELECT aa.*, 
(SELECT CONCAT(n1,",",n2,",",n3,",",n4,",",n5,",",n6) FROM table bb WHERE bb.id=aa.id ORDER BY FIELD(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6) asc) AS conc 
FROM table aa 
WHERE aa.id=1
```

I know is a childish approach, but I have no idea how to get the right result.

Comment: Please share your attempt(s) so we can help guide you on where you went wrong.

Comment: Unpivot (UNION ALL), aggregate with sorting, parse back.

Comment: Hi @Akina , how can I do that? Can you show me? Thanks!

Comment: That is one reason to avoid having an "array" spread across columns.  Instead, these should be 8 rows of another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(n ORDER BY n), ',', 1), ',', -1) AS n1,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(n ORDER BY n), ',', 2), ',', -1) AS n2,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(n ORDER BY n), ',', 3), ',', -1) AS n3,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(n ORDER BY n), ',', 4), ',', -1) AS n4,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(n ORDER BY n), ',', 5), ',', -1) AS n5,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(n ORDER BY n), ',', 6), ',', -1) AS n6
FROM (
    SELECT id, n1 AS n FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, n2 AS n FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, n3 AS n FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, n4 AS n FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, n5 AS n FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, n6 AS n FROM table
    ) AS unpivotted
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but you should care if they have the same number

```
select
id,
case when n1 < n2 and n1 < n3 then n1 
    else case when n2 < n3 and n2 < n1 then n2
    else case when n3 < n2 and n3 < n1 then n3
    end end end as n1,
... as n2,
... as n3
from table 
where id = 1
```